# Variable scope is incorrectly global

Tags: python

My `original` variable seems to be *global* since it is changed after passing a function, `updateSudoku`. From my understanding, the variable scope inside a function should be local to that function only. Could someone explain why code is failing?

For example, the value in the lower left corner has correctly been changed but a test on my variable show that they are equal. Somehow, along the way, I changed the variable `original` without referring to it.

From the python documentation, I found the following but I am not sure how it helps me out.
In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.

Code:

```
def print_sudoku(board):
    print("-"*37)
    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        print(("|" + " {}   {}   {} |"*3).format(*[x if x != 0 else " " for x in row]))
        if i == 8:
            print("-"*37)
        elif i % 3 == 2:
            print("|" + "---+"*8 + "---|")
        else:
            print("|" + "   +"*8 + "   |")

original = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 7, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 6, 7, 3, 1, 0, 8, 0, 9], [8, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7], [0, 2, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 1, 3], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0], [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0], [0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]]

updates = [[], [], [(1, [(8, 0)])], [(1, [(2, 5)])], [], [], [], [], []]

print_sudoku(original)

def updateSudoku(sudoku, updates):

    newVar=sudoku

    for b in updates:
        for soln in b:
            newVar[soln[1][0][0]][soln[1][0][1]]=soln[0] 


    return newVar

newSudoku=updateSudoku(original, updates)

print_sudoku(newSudoku)
print(original==newSudoku)
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------
|         1 |     3     |           |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
|     3     |         6 | 1   7     |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
|           |           |     3     |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|     6   7 | 3   1     | 8       9 |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
| 8   1   3 | 4         | 5       7 |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
|     2     |     8   7 |     1   3 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
| 3         |           | 7         |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
| 7         |           | 3   5     |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
|         6 |         3 |           |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
|         1 |     3     |           |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
|     3     |         6 | 1   7     |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
|           |         1 |     3     |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|     6   7 | 3   1     | 8       9 |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
| 8   1   3 | 4         | 5       7 |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
|     2     |     8   7 |     1   3 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
| 3         |           | 7         |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
| 7         |           | 3   5     |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
| 1       6 |         3 |           |
-------------------------------------
True
```

Comment: ? As you say, "the variable scope inside a function should be local to that function only". `original` is not defined inside a function. Therefore it is global. In the function `updateSudoku`, however, you change it as it is an *argument* to that function. Were you expecting it not to change it in there?

Comment: @usr2564301 I modified the code to show that i assigned it a new variable inside the function.  That `newVar` should be local and distinct from `original`. I still run into the same issue.

Comment: That is by design. Assigning a variable that points to a list will point to the same list.

Comment: @Jrakru56 the variable is local, but it is referring to the same object. Assignment doesn't copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global scope is irrelevant in this case.

What is going on here is that you have passed `original`, which is a list, as a parameter to the `updateSudoku()` function. Lists are mutable objects, therefore any modification you make to the list within that function will modify the list in place. It will change the `original` list's contents.

If you want to avoid this, you should deep copy the list within the function.

I recommend:

- [Python Basics: Mutable vs Immutable Objects](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-towardsdatascience-com-python-basics-mutable-vs-immutable-objects-829a0cb1530a)
- [Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)
- [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: I was barking at the wrong tree. `copy.deepcopy` fixed it. Thanks!